# How many non-congruent triangles can be formed by the vertices of a regular polygon of $n$ sides

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

On a circle there are $n$ evenly spaced points (i.e., they form a regular polygon). How many triangles can be formed when congruent triangles are considered the same?

This question is closely related to
[How many triangles can be formed by the vertices of a regular polygon of $n$ sides?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446438/how-many-triangles-can-be-formed-by-the-vertices-of-a-regular-polygon-of-n-sid), but here congruent triangles are considered to be the same.

Comment: Have you attempted any examples for small $n$?  Do you see a pattern?  For each triangle type, can you find a standard form for that triangle?

Comment: for n=3,4, clearly 1; for n=5, should be 2; for n=6, should be 3; etc. I think n=12 (clock), it should be 12, but I am not sure

Comment: http://oeis.org/A001399

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each triangle $A_iA_jA_k$, the angles $\angle A_iOA_j$, $\angle A_jOA_k$ and $\angle A_kOA_i$ are respectively equal to $|j-i|\frac{2\pi}{n}$, $|j-k|\frac{2\pi}{n}$  and $|k-i|\frac{2\pi}{n}$ with $1\le i\ne j\ne k \le (n-1)$.

Let denote
$$
\begin{cases}
x=|j-i|\\
y=|k-j|\\
z=|k-i|
\end{cases}
$$

Then
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y+z = n \\
x,y,z \in \Bbb N^* \\
\end{cases}  \tag{1}
$$

The number of triangles when congruent triangles are considered the same is equal to the number of solutions of $(1)$ (Two solutions that differ only in the order of their summands are considered the same, for example, with $n = 4$: $1+1+2$ is the same as $2 +1 +1$).

The problem $(1)$ is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217597/195378) and the number of solutions of $(1)$ is the number of partitions $p(3,n)$ of $n$ into $3$ non-zero parts. The number of partitions $p(k,n)$ satisfies
$$
\begin{cases}
p(0,0) &= 0 \\
p(k,n) &= p(k,n-k)+ p(k-1,n-1) & \text{otherwise}. \\
\end{cases} \tag{2}
$$
*Remark:* It seems that the recurrent formula in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217641/195378) is not correct, the recurrent formula $(2)$ is taken from [the wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts).
From $(2)$, we can deduce the general formula of $p(3,n)$ as follows

- For $k = 1$, it's obvious that
  $$p(1,n) = 1$$
- For $k =1$, we have
  $$p(2,n) = p(2,n-2)+1 =... \implies p(2,n) = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$$
- For $k = 3$, we have
  $$p(3,n) =p(3,n-3)+\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rfloor=...$$

$$
\begin{align}
\implies p(3,n) &=\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{n-4}{2} \right\rfloor+...+\left\lfloor \frac{n-1-3i}{2} \right\rfloor+... \\
& =\sum_{0 \le i \le \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{n-1-3i}{2} \right\rfloor
\end{align}
$$

Hence, the number of triangles is equal to
$$p(3,n)=\sum_{0 \le i \le \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{3} \right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{n-1-3i}{2} \right\rfloor$$

*Remark*: The last steps have a lot of calculation, please feel free to correct if you find any mistake.

Comment: $$\left\lfloor\frac{n^2+3}{12}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: @bof: does your formula come from oeis.org/A001399 ? If yes, perhaps, there is a way to simplify my formula to yours and a proof by recurrence will work.

Comment: The formula in my comment is from my notebook from a combinatorics class I took many years ago. It was homework and I think I proved it by cases: $n\equiv0\pmod6$, $n\equiv1\pmod6$, etc.